# Idiomatic way to continuously poll a HTTP server and dispatch to an actor

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I need to write a client that continuously polls a web server for commands. A response from the server indicates that a command is available (in which case the response contains the command) or an instruction that no command is available, and you should fire off a new request for incoming commands.

I'm trying to figure out how to do it using spray-client and Akka, and I can think of ways to do it, but none of them look like they're the idiomatic way to get it done. So the question is:

> what's the most sensible way to have a couple of threads poll the same web server for incoming commands and hand the commands off to an actor?

Comment: Don't you have control over the server? If you do, having it use a websocket and using a websocket client looks much more appealing than polling it continuously.

Comment: No, I don't. Not something I can negotiate. This is how they work.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses [spray-client](http://spray.io/documentation/spray-client/#message-pipeline), [scala futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/futures.html), and [Akka scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/scheduler.html).

Implementation varies depending on desired behavior (execute many requests in parallel at the same time, execute in different intervals, send responses to one actor to process one response at a time, send responses to many actors to process in parallel... etc).

This particular example shows how execute many requests in parallel at the same time, and then do something with each result as it completes, without waiting for any other requests that were fired off at the same time to complete.

The code below will execute two HTTP requests every 5 seconds to 0.0.0.0:9000/helloWorld and 0.0.0.0:9000/goodbyeWorld in parallel.

Tested in Scala 2.10, Spray 1.1-M7, and Akka 2.1.2:

Actual scheduling code that handles periodic job execution:

```
// Schedule a periodic task to occur every 5 seconds, starting as soon 
// as this schedule is registered
system.scheduler.schedule(initialDelay = 0 seconds, interval = 5 seconds) {

  val paths = Seq("helloWorld", "goodbyeWorld")

  // perform an HTTP request to 0.0.0.0:9000/helloWorld and 
  // 0.0.0.0:9000/goodbyeWorld
  // in parallel (possibly, depending on available cpu and cores)
  val retrievedData = Future.traverse(paths) { path =>
    val response = fetch(path)
    printResponse(response)
    response
  }
}
```

Helper methods / boilerplate setup:

```
// Helper method to fetch the body of an HTTP endpoint as a string
def fetch(path: String): Future[String] = {
  pipeline(HttpRequest(method = GET, uri = s"/$path"))

}

// Helper method for printing a future'd string asynchronously
def printResponse(response: Future[String]) {
  // Alternatively, do response.onComplete {...}
  for (res <- response) {
    println(res)
  }
}


// Spray client boilerplate
val ioBridge = IOExtension(system).ioBridge()
val httpClient = system.actorOf(Props(new HttpClient(ioBridge)))

// Register a "gateway" to a particular host for HTTP requests 
// (0.0.0.0:9000 in this case)
val conduit = system.actorOf(
  props = Props(new HttpConduit(httpClient, "0.0.0.0", 9000)),
  name = "http-conduit"
)

// Create a simple pipeline to deserialize the request body into a string
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[String] = {
  sendReceive(conduit) ~> unmarshal[String]
}
```

Some notes:

- `Future.traverse` is used for running futures in parallel (ignores order). Using a for comprehension on a list of futures will execute one future at a time, waiting for each to complete.

  ```
  // Executes `oneThing`, executes `andThenAnother` when `oneThing` is complete,
  // then executes `finally` when `andThenAnother` completes.
  for {
    oneThing <- future1
    andThenAnother <- future2
    finally <- future3
  } yield (...)
  ```
- `system` will need to be replaced with your actual Akka actor system.
- `system.scheduler.schedule` in this case is executing an arbitrary block of code every 5 seconds -- there is also an overloaded version for scheduling messages to be sent to an actorRef.

  ```
  system.scheduler.schedule(
    initialDelay = 0 seconds,
    frequency    = 30 minutes,
    receiver     = rssPoller, // an actorRef
    message      = "doit" // the message to send to the actorRef
  )
  ```
- For your particular case, printResponse can be replaced with an actor send instead: `anActorRef ! response`.
- The code sample doesn't take into account failures -- a good place to handle failures would be in the printResponse (or equivalent) method, by using a Future onComplete callback: `response.onComplete {...}`
- Perhaps obvious, but spray-client can be replaced with another http client, just replace the `fetch` method and accompanying spray code.

**Update:** Full running code example is [here](https://github.com/daniel-trinh/webcrawler/blob/840a4bc50430b02ccc777c2637b53c89dc24d54a/app/biz/HttpPoller.scala):

git clone the repo, checkout the specified commit sha, `$ sbt run`, navigate to `0.0.0.0:9000`, and watch the code in the console where `sbt run` was executed -- it should print `Hello World!\n'Goodbye World!` OR `Goodbye World!\nHelloWorld!` (order is potentially random because of parallel Future.traverse execution).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML5 Server-Sent Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/). It is implemented in many Scala frameworks. For example in [xitrum](http://ngocdaothanh.github.com/xitrum/guide/async.html?highlight=respondeventsource#event-source) code looks like:

```
class SSE extends Controller {
  def sse = GET("/sse") {
    addConnectionClosedListener {
      // The connection has been closed
      // Unsubscribe from events, release resources etc.
    }

    future {
        respondEventSource("command1")
        //...
        respondEventSource("command2")
        //...
    }
 }
```

SSE is pretty simple and can be used in any software not only in browser.
Akka integrated in xitrum and we use it in similar system. But it uses netty for async server it is also good for processing thousands of request in 10-15 threads.

So in this way your client will keep connection with server and reconnect when connection will be broken.